# How do I get images from an android app made using opengl (filament rather)?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, opengl-es, google-filament

I want to generate a synthetic dataset and for certain reasons I can only use the filament rendering engines. I thought I would store screenshots for every case, but I am unable to even get those. I have no experience using android studio or Kotlin, and I am only doing this to generate dataset. If anyone could suggest how to extract images/ frames from the app that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone looks it up in the future, I used PixelCopy to store the rendered image.